# force:inputfield is not displayed on the modal popup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, popup, modal

I have created modal in component and added `<force:inputField` inside it, but it is not displayed on the modal popup.

[image]

But, if the same `<force:inputField` is added in the component, then it displayed on the component.

[image]

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="contactOnAccount" type="Custom_Opportunity_Contact_Role__c" 
               default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Custom_Opportunity_Contact_Role__c' }"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.editOCRModal}">
        <div aura:id="new-ocr" class="" style="">
            <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1"  class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container main-modal-container slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                    <div class="slds-modal__header">
                        <div aura:id="new_ocr_setting_modal" class="slds-text-heading--small modal-header">New Priority Points Settings</div>
                        <div class="close_modal"> 
                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="Close" iconClass="light" size="x-small" class="add_ocr" onclick="{!c.closeModal}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium content">
                        <label class="slds-custom-label">Contact</label> 

                        <force:inputField aura:id="test_lookup_field" value="{!v.contactOnAccount.Contact__c}"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
```

How to display force:inputfield on the modal popup?

Comment: Do you see any error in console? I literally copy pasted your code except for the SObject type here and it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Force:InputField / OutputField  nested in aura:if will not render when default value is false
[For More Info...](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCebQAE)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`aura:renderIf`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:renderIf/documentation) it will work. No other workaround

The difference being that [`aura:if`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation) instantiates the components in both the "if" and "else" attributes, but not both. `aura:renderIf` instantiates both, then only renders one.